R3InjectorError Error " No provider for _HttpClient! "
I got this error message "ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!"  while trying to upload and save gifs through backend, nd there are some settings that I get from the backend of my application.
There is my app.module.ts
// app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RootComponent } from './root.component'; // Import RootComponent
import { GifDetailComponent } from '../gif/gif-detail.component'; // Import GifDetailComponent
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UploadComponent } from '../Upload/upload.component'; // Import UploadComponent
import { UploadModule } from '../Upload/upload.module'; // Import UploadModule

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RootComponent, // Declare RootComponent
    GifDetailComponent,
    
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UploadModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ RootComponent ] // Bootstrap RootComponent
  
})
export class AppModule { }

Upload.module.ts
// upload.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Import FormsModule
import { UploadComponent } from './upload.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UploadComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    
    FormsModule, // Use FormsModule instead of ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [UploadComponent]
})
export class UploadModule { }

Any ideas what should i do?
There is a my github link : https://github.com/BekaEn/GifApp

You should do your HTTP requests in a service, then you probably don't have this issue.

UPDATE:
The provided Repo, is having a lot of issues, due to mixing of SSR and modules, I would suggest you start a fresh project with either standalone components or modular components, this repo will keep giving you issues going forward.
Standalone: ng new <<project name>> --routing
Standalone: ng new <<project name>> --standalone=false --routing

You are having a separate module UploadModule which I guess is lazy loaded, so you need to import the HttpClientModule separately inorder for it to work!
// upload.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Import FormsModule
import { UploadComponent } from './upload.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UploadComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule, // <--------- changed here!
    FormsModule, // Use FormsModule instead of ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [UploadComponent]
})
export class UploadModule { }

If you do not want to repeat the imports, create a common module and export the contents, where you can import to all your lazy loaded modules and imports will be shared!
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    FormsModule, 
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule, 
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

You can use this to import the exported features to any module you want!
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UploadComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule, // <--------- changed here!
  ],
  exports: [UploadComponent]
})
export class UploadModule { }

We Also need to add provideHttpClient() to the app.config.ts to solve the issue, because http client is not added in server.ts
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

Working reference branch
Github Fork

Tried your version but i still have the same issue.
